# Is it possible to lower the slope of a biquad lowpass?

Tags: filters, lowpass-filter, biquad

I'd like to implement a lowpass with arbitrary slope. I'm currently cascading biquads in order to get a higher order, hence higher slope. But is it possible to do the opposite - lower the slope of one biquad? Normally one would be 12db/oct, so anything lower than that. Sort of mixing with dry signal, but without the phase cancellation. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You want less slope than -12 dB per octave (or -40 dB per decade)?  Certainly, with zeros beside the poles, you can get ***less*** performance.  What are you trying to do?  Pink noise?

Comment: Could this type of design method be used with LPF :  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/29974/how-to-calculate-biquad-coefficients-for-the-partial-1-10-applying-of-pre-e/30086#30086